# Time series mock data generation for 16 years of quarterly data in Excel or Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I would like to generate a mock time series quarterly dataset from, say, 2000-2016 for a variable (quarterly credit growth) that averages around a certain value (say, 30%). Can anyone give a suggestion on how to do this in principle? 
Edit: what I was implying were the actual data values for each time period, i.e. data with a certain mean and variance.

Found a solution with a code in Matlab, for anyone interested, see below in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Excel approach:

You can make column A your date list.  In A1, or A2 or more if you have header rows, you will have to seed your list by providing the first start date. Lets assume you put your seed date in A2.  I would then go about adding 3 month to you start date using a formula, and copy down until you have hit your desired date.  In order to add the 3 months I would use the following in A3.

```
=date(year(A2),Month(A2)+3,day(A1)
```

that will give you the first day of the month every 3 months.  If you want the first day of the month every 3 months, set the day to 1 like so:

```
=date(year(A2),Month(A2)+3,day(A1)
```

And end of month could be calculated as:

```
=eomonth(date(year(A2),Month(A2)+3,day(A1)),0)
```

however I would prefer to do the end of month calculation based on the row you are in so I would do it more like:

```
=EOMONTH($A$2,(rows($A$2:A3)-1)*3)
```

Comment: Thank you @Forward Ed. This solution is for creating the dates/times of the dataset, which indeed is suitable. What I was implying with my question, was the creation of mock values for my variables, i.e. values for variable x at t=1 and so forth.

I tried in matlab and succeeded with :

rng(0,'twister');
a = 5;
b = 10;
y = a.*randn(99,1) + b;
stats = [mean(y) std(y) var(y)]

which generated 99 random data with average 10 and standard dev of 5.

Comment: ok, what you just put in this comment about what you were implying, should really go into your original question as an edit.  I unfortunately do not speak Matlab so I will not be able to help you on that front.  if this is statistics, you may which to add that tag to your question.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion.